# RichTextBox Text Events

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am getting a VERY annoying behavior trying to use the WPF `RichTextBox` events for some text manipulation.

The idea is to have some logic that will extract the `RichTextBox` text once some criteria is met.

The issue is that `TextChanged` event is almost perfect, I can get all the text I want BUT the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is ignored on `TextChanged` and the event is never fired.

So `PreviewKeyDown` would be the correct one, right? Wrong. `PreviewKeyDown` only returns the text BEFORE the last key was pressed...and just `KeyDown` will ignore the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key too. Also, `KeyUp` is not an option as well because I want to be able to block certain keys to be typed.

## **Is there a event where I can get the whole text of a `RichTextBox` including the <kbd>Enter</kbd>?**

---

Edit:

I am building a `TokenizingRichTextBox` following pretty much [this tutorial](https://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/), with some minor modifications (I made it into a Blend Behavior instead of a new kind of Control).

The problem is when the user types <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Only the text on the last paragraph gets added to the new `Token`. I would like to user the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the <kbd>Tab</kbd> (among other characters) to trigger the `Token` creation. But I can't, as mentioned before because the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is ignored.

Also, although this can be fixed with some Key events, I intent to add some kind of `AutoComplete` to the `RichTextBox`. With the `AutoComplete` none of the Key events will be triggered, just the `TextChanged` so taking this into account makes things even more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The TextChanged event *is* fired, and the newline has already been entered into document at that stage. To get the exact text changed, do something like

```
var doc =  richTextBox.Document;
foreach(var c in evt.Changes.Where(x => x.AddedLength > 1))
{
    var change = new TextRange(
        doc.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(c.Offset),
        doc.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(c.Offset + c.AddedLength));
    Debug.WriteLine($"Change: <{change.Text}>");                
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I would like to be able to block some keys, and `KeyUp` doesn't provide the `e.Handled = true` to block a key from being typed. I will update my question.

Comment: I'm sorry as well - you're talking about wpf, and I was testing winforms :)

Comment: I should have made that clearer instead of just the wpf tag.

Comment: As far as I can see the `RichTextBox` adds a new `Run` on each `Enter`. The problem is matching the whole text with the different `Run`s where they are. I am building a tokenizing `RichTextBox` and matching the text with the `Runs` is important to know where to match the new token inlines. If I use your method I will indeed get the whole text with the `Enter`, but the problem will be worse later to match the text with the `Runs`.